# Building multiple pages - php insert from database?

Tags: php, database, insert, html

I'm not sure whether this is in the right area, but I have to create about 300 pages all about different areas.

This is going to take ages, but what I thought I could do is use a PHP script to pull the data into a webpage template (My premade page without content) then saves the file under a file name in the database.

I was asking if anyone had done something similar and could point me in the right direction, searching through Google doesn't help because I’m not entirely sure what I’m looking for!

Comment: If you don't know what you are looking for then you should know that stackoverflow is the wrong place and I mean no harm.

Comment: Well ok I know near enough what I want, just not specfics or the right terms, but due to this being a techincal question I thought it may be some-what valid, Sorry if it's not!